# How to Sort JSON Decode by Number Values in Foreach PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON data

```
{
    "items":[
                {"country":"AE","counts":145,"seen":785 },
                {"country":"AR","counts":786,"seen":442},
                {"country":"AT","counts":132,"seen":743}
            ]
}
```

I need to sort array by counts or seen within foreach loop like numbers descending

Here's my code

```
$jsonobj = json_decode($json, true);
//////////////////////////
foreach($jsonobj['items'] as $items){
    usort($jsonobj, "custom_sort");
    function custom_sort($a,$b) {
      return $a['counts']>$b['counts'];
    }
    $country = $items['country'];
    $counts = $items['counts'];
    $seen = $items['seen'];
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Start by reading the [PHP Manual - Sorting Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: _Future Reference_ If you have a JSON String, then post the JSONString, not a representation of it. We have no idea if it is in fact a valid JSONString the way you show it to us. Also we cannot copy/paste that easily into some test code either. If you make our help easy to give, you will get more of it

Comment: You'll want to look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php. You'll need to write a custom function to compare the desired keys of your items.

Comment: A little better, now did you lookup `uasort` like you were suggested to?

Comment: yes i have tried many suggestions over stackoverflow and php.net site but none worked for me

Comment: Ok, so show us your best try, or at least your last try, then we have something to work from

Comment: edited my question with my last try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your attempt:

1. it produces an error because the custom_sort function is declared after the usort function which tries to use it. Move it beforehand (and out of the loop, it makes no sense to keep repeating it). You should have noticed this when trying to run it, although you didn't mention it in your question.
2. You don't need a loop anyway - usort will work on the whole array at once
3. You're passing the wrong thing to usort - it needs to work on the "items" property within your object, that's where the array is.
4. Your comparison function is backwards - it needs to check less than, rather than greater than, if you want to sort in descending order
5. Returning booleans from the custom sort function is deprecated - you get a warning which tells you to return an integer instead.

This code fixes all of the problems I've listed:

```
$json = '{"items":[{"country":"AE","counts":145,"seen":785},{"country":"AR","counts":786,"seen":442},{"country":"AT","counts":132,"seen":743}]}';
$jsonobj = json_decode($json, true);

function custom_sort($a,$b) {
    return $a['counts'] < $b['counts'] ? 1 : 0;
}

usort($jsonobj["items"], "custom_sort");
var_dump($jsonobj);
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dff4ed04f7c332704438fc5225f8de936a389221

Comment: Thank a lot @ADyson you been a great help